# Change WooCommerce product price based on category and GEO IP country

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a very specific question. In Belgium we need to add a BEBAT tax when you sell batteries. I'm now trying to figure out how I can tackle this.

The code below works until a certain part so I hope I'm close but I can't seem to find the issue and hope you guys can help me.

I'm checking via IP to see what country you're in. Based on country, I want to add an extra fee of (for example) .99 and add this only on the products that have a certain category (for example batteries).

But with the code below, it shows on all products even if they are not in the category.

I also need to figure out how I can add this as text on the product and show the same message on the invoice. All tips are welcome!

```
function add_tax_bebat() {
    $getIp      = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ipDetails  = json_decode( @file_get_contents( "http://ipinfo.io/{$getIp}/json" ) );
    $country    = $ipDetails->country;

    if ( $country =="BE" ){
        function return_custom_price($price, $products) {
            $args = array(
                'category'  => array( 'batteries' ),
            );
            $products = wc_get_products( $args );
            $price = ($price+0.99);

            return $price;
        }
        add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
    }
}
add_action ( 'init', 'add_tax_bebat' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce has already a Geo IP feature that you can use through `WC_Geolocation` Class.

I have revisited completely your code. To target a product category you can use WordPress [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function on WooCommerce Product Category custom taxonomy as follow:

```
function is_geo_country_belgium() {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
    $geolocation_instance = new WC_Geolocation();
    // Get user IP
    $user_ip_address = $geolocation_instance->get_ip_address();
    // Get geolocated user IP country code.
    $user_geolocation = $geolocation_instance->geolocate_ip( $user_ip_address );

    return $user_geolocation['country'] === 'BE' ? true : false;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'change_specific_products_price', 10, 2 );
function change_specific_products_price( $price, $product ) {
    $category = 'batteries';

    if ( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && is_geo_country_belgium() ) {
        $price += 0.99;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and works.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec,

Thank you very much for the solutions! This is a much better way to tackle it. I couldn't figure this out myself.

Thanks!